# Silverlight 4 tab order problem?

Tags: silverlight, tabbing

I’d like to find out if I am missing something in my XAML code related to the tabbing. In my case, I need to click twice to be able to advance to the next control in the tab order. It will be great to find out the proper way applying tabbing in Silverlight 4. Below is the code I use for tabbing. Thank you in advance!

```
<StackPanel x:Name="sp" Grid.Column="0" >
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtO" Style="{StaticResource AVV_TitleStyleBlue}" Text="Text" />
                <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hl1" Style="{StaticResource AVV_HyperlinkButtonStyle}" Content="test 1" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="11" />
                <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hl2" Style="{StaticResource AVV_HyperlinkButtonStyle}" Content="test 2" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="12"/>
                <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hl3" Style="{StaticResource AVV_HyperlinkButtonStyle}" Content="test 3" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="13" />
                <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hl4" Style="{StaticResource AVV_HyperlinkButtonStyle}" Content="test 4" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="14" />
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the question (whats happening versus what you need to do)?  Testing the code without the styles, the tabbing seems to work fine.

Comment: probably something in the style takes focus

Comment: The problem is that I need to click twice to select the next item in the tabbing order. Thank you for looking.

Comment: The issue persists even if I remove styles.

Answer (score 0):

You might have the issue where a sub control is also getting the tab, i guess that since you need to tab twice. On the first tab is most likely taking you to a hidden control, The second tab then takes you to the control you want. To fix this you need to find out what control the focus is going to when you hit Tab. You can do that by using the Focus Manager's get Focused Component method; you put that in a place just after you hit tab, you may need a small delay  before getting the control. Then you set a break point in VS, and get the info about that control. Once found you set its IsTabStop Property to false. If you are using a third party control, you will need to change its template maybe using expression blend.